# Not editable textfield in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, textfield

I want to define a not editable textfield in ruby on rails with a default value assigned. I tried so but it doesn't recognize the readonly method:

```
<%= f.text_field :email,:value=> current_user.email, :readonly=>readonly %>
```

Comment: Use `:readonly => true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make a form field read-only, set the `readonly` attribute, like others have pointed out:

```
f.text_field :email, :value => current_user.email, :readonly => true
```

Just setting it on the form isnt enough, you need to protect this attribute in the model layer too:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_readonly :email
end
```

The documentation on `attr_readonly`:

"Attributes listed as readonly will be used to create a new record but update operations will ignore these fields."

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `:readonly => true` not `:readonly=>readonly`

```
<%= f.text_field :email,:value=> current_user.email, :readonly=>true %>
```

It will make it as a **`non-editable text_field`** and allows the params of that textfield to pass to the controller.

Here is small **[code](https://coderwall.com/p/r2cqhg)** which tells the differences between **`:readonly => true`** and **`:disabled => true`**

Answer (score 0):

the attribute should be `:disabled => "disabled"`

Comment: @Santosh the value for :disabled should be a string "disabled", not true.